# mysqli_query returns false to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need help. I have a query:

```
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
......
$m = $_GET['m'];
$sql = "SELECT CID,name from course WHERE major='$m'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)!=0){..... etc
```

where $m is a valid variable, and db_conx.php is code for connecting to database. But my $query is returning false,  i checked my query seperately in my php my admin, so it is valid. I suspect that it is due to that somehow i am not able to connec to the database. However this works in localhost, and don't on a real server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checks for errors?

Comment: ^^thats so crazy it might work

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Plus, `$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));` - You have enough to debug.

Comment: @Dagon Ye think? ^ that is crazy - *Johnny Carson*

Comment: **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)**

Comment: Never assume success. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a plesant surprise: e.g. do exactly what @fred's suggesting.